# DropBox (without API), need to get the hash/code for the file so I can open its share interface

Tags: dropbox

Without using DropBox API, I need to be able to construct the URL that will open the share page for the user.  I know the full path of the file, but what I don't know is the hash/code that appears in the share link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/81b1yhj722rz1k2/test0306b.sdr

In the above example, 81b1yhj722rz1k2 is the code I'm looking for.  I know the userid.  Was hoping that it would be a hash of the userid and the path, but wasn't able to come up with anything that produced the correct results.  The Chooser apparently will give me that value, but I can't have the user interacting with the Chooser.  Perhaps a way to silently invoke the Chooser passing it the file path as an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without using the API. The hash that goes in the URL is derived from a server-side secret. Using the Core API, you can get this via [`/shares`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares).

Is there some reason you're unwilling/unable to use the API?

Comment: My application is c/c++.  There's no core API for that environment.

Comment: The API is HTTP-based, so you can call it from any language that has an HTTP stack (including, of course, C).